# Handle URL custom scheme on Qt Android

Tags: android, qt

I'm very new to Qt. I want to handle a custom URL scheme (myapp://) in Qt. For iOS I got it working, but not for Android.

In AndroidManifest.xml I added to the existing activity: (android:name="org.qtproject.qt5.android.bindings.QtActivity") the following intent filter:

```
<intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />
        <data android:scheme="myapp"/>
    </intent-filter>
```

And in main.cpp I have:

```
HandleURL *URLHandler = new HandleURL();
    QDesktopServices::setUrlHandler("myapp", URLHandler, "handleURL");
```

How can I link QtActivity with the QDesktopServices::setUrlHandler to get the contents of the URL?

Comment: I am facing a similar problem and I am beginning to be persuaded that you have to use the JNI and extend QtActivity. Did you get any result?

Comment: This might help: https://forum.qt.io/topic/97897/how-to-handle-filter-intent-on-android-properly-on-android/5